# XProc - How to repeat a subpipeline for a specific number of times

Tags: xpath, xproc

I'd like to repeat a XProc subpipeline for a given number of times. (In my usecase the subpipeline consists of an exec-step, that runs LaTeX over a previously created .tex-file)

A simplified version of my code looks like the following, that gives no result so far:

```
<p:declare-step  version="1.0"
xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step">

<p:option name="latex-exec" select="'uri/latex'"/>
<p:option name="latex-repeat" select="3"/>
<p:option name="tmp-path" select="'uri/tmp/'"/>
<p:option name="tmp-file" select="'tmp'"/>

<!-- pre-processing -->

<p:for-each>
    <p:iteration-source select="(1 to $latex-repeat)"/>

    <p:exec result-is-xml="false">
        <p:with-option name="command" select="$latex-exec"/>
        <p:with-option name="args"    select="string-join(('-interaction=nonstopmode','-halt-on-error','-output-format=pdf',concat('-output-directory=',$tmp-path),concat($tmp-path,$tmp-file,'.tex')),' ')"/>
        <p:input port="source">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:exec>
</p:for-each>
```

I don't know if it is an issue with the XPath-2.0 expression in the p:iteration-source element. However, the following works and gives the correct result "Message: 3":

```
<cx:message>
    <p:with-option name="message" select="count((1 to $latex-repeat))"/>
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
</cx:message>
```

My exec-step is tested outside the for-each loop and works. I am working with Calabash under Oxygen 16.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you can only iterate over XML documents in XProc 1.0. Since the `select` expression in your `p:iteration-source` produces a sequence of numbers, not documents, the pipeline will fail with a dynamic error (most likely `err:XD0001: It is a dynamic error if a non-XML resource is produced on a step output or arrives on a step input.`)

(The reason why the example with `cx:message` works is that the `p:with-option` construct binds a value to an option and the result of the `select` XPath expression is then treated as `xs:untypedAtomic`.)

To loop *n* number of times, you will have to use recursion, like in the following example (untested but you should get the idea):

```
<p:declare-step version="1.0"
                xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
                xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step"
                xmlns:my="http://example.org/latex-process"
                type="my:latex-process">

  <p:option name="latex-exec" select="'uri/latex'"/>
  <p:option name="latex-repeat" select="3"/>
  <p:option name="tmp-path" select="'uri/tmp/'"/>
  <p:option name="tmp-file" select="'tmp'"/>

  <p:choose>
    <p:when test="$latex-repeat = 0">
      <p:sink>
        <p:input port="source">
          <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
      </p:sink>
    </p:when>
    <p:otherwise>
      <p:exec result-is-xml="false">
        <p:with-option name="command" select="$latex-exec"/>
        <p:with-option name="args"    select="string-join(('-interaction=nonstopmode','-halt-on-error','-output-format=pdf',concat('-output-directory=',$tmp-path),concat($tmp-path,$tmp-file,'.tex')),' ')"/>
        <p:input port="source">
          <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
      </p:exec>
      <my:latex-exec>
        <p:with-option name="latex-exec" select="$latex-exec"/>
        <p:with-option name="latex-repeat" select="$latex-repeat - 1"/>
        <p:with-option name="tmp-path" select="$tmp-path"/>
        <p:with-option name="tmp-file" select="$tmp-file"/>
      </my:latex-exec>
    </p:otherwise>
  </p:choose>
</p:declare-step>
```

Comment: In my example no error is thrown, probably because the select expression is ignored all together when the input is empty? If a valid, non-empty input is provided, [err:XD0016](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#err.inline.D0016) (not err:XD0001) is thrown.

So, a p:for-each with the following source declaration does not throw errors for any XPath expression, nor will it ever iterate?:  `<p:iteration-source select="..."><p:empty/></p:iteration-source>`

Then, why allow a p:empty as iteration source, anyway?

Comment: Your alternative proposition should do the trick. I give another alternative solution that keeps the iteration functionalities separated from the sub-pipeline (see my answer). Unfortunately both, your and my solution, come a little long winded - I would have loved a more straightforward approach to iterations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Vojtěch Toman the p:for-each loop can't iterate over atomic values [[XD0016](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#err.D0016)]. As this restriction does not apply to the XSLT 2.0 loop equivalent we can define our own p:xslt step to create a sequence of XML nodes according to the number of desired iterations. Then this sequence can be used as input for a p:for-each.

The iterator step would look as follows:

```
<p:declare-step version="1.0"
    xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step"
    xmlns:my="http://example.org/iterate"
    type="my:iterator">

    <p:option name="iterate" required="true"/>

    <p:input port="source"/>
    <p:output port="result" sequence="true"/>

    <p:xslt name="iterator" template-name="iterator">
        <p:with-param name="iterator" select="$iterate"/>
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:inline>
                <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
                    <xsl:param name="iterator"/>
                    <xsl:template name="iterator">
                        <xsl:for-each select="(1 to xs:integer($iterator))">
                            <xsl:result-document href="{position()}">
                                <iterate/>
                            </xsl:result-document>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
            </p:inline>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="source">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>

    <p:sink/>

    <p:identity>
        <p:input port="source">
            <p:pipe port="secondary" step="iterator"/>
        </p:input>
    </p:identity>

</p:declare-step>
```

An example using the new iterator step would look as follows:

```
<p:declare-step version="1.0"
    xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step"
    xmlns:my="http://example.org/iterate">

    <p:import href="iterate.xpl"/>

    <!-- pre-processing -->    

    <my:iterator>
        <p:with-option name="iterate" select="3"/>
    </my:iterator>
    <p:for-each>

        <!-- sub-pipeline -->

    </p:for-each>

</p:declare-step>
```